# Parsing this XML file to a Dictionary?

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, dictionary, xna

I'm very new to XML serialization, up until now I've been using XDocument and iterating through an XML file to load stuff up. I know there's a way to serialize XML files, recently I came across the following bit of XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<XnaContent>
<Asset Type="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[System.String, Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle]">
<Item><Key>frame0</Key><Value>0 0 128 128</Value></Item>
<Item><Key>frame1</Key><Value>128 0 128 128</Value></Item>
</Asset>
</XnaContent>
```

And have been trying to figure out how I'd load it up and parse it into a dictionary, the top part stating asset type=System.collections.generic.dictionary seems to suggest I should be able to quickly convert this into a dictionary.

So my question is how would I do that? I could easily iterate through the xml structure and match up keys to values but it looks like there would be a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's surprisingly straight forward. **Add the XML file to your content project**. Keep the default importer ("XML Content") and processor (none).

The XNA content pipeline will build it into an `XNB` file for you.

Then simply load it with `ContentManager.Load` like you would any other asset:

```
var myContent = Content.Load<Dictionary<string, Rectangle>>("MyXmlFile");
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Having just skimmed [this article](http://jamesewelch.wordpress.com/2008/04/17/how-to-use-xnacontent-xml-files/) and [this one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2008/05/30/xml-and-the-content-pipeline.aspx), I suspect you want to use either [`IntermediateSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.content.pipeline.serialization.intermediate.intermediateserializer.aspx) or [`XmlImporter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.content.pipeline.xmlimporter.aspx).

Not being an XNA developer, it's unclear to me how it all fits together, but hopefully that's enough to get you started.

Of course, if this was just an *example* of XML and you're actually wanting to serialize data that isn't part of XNA, you may want to look at [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx). Personally I've found it simpler to control the serialization manually using LINQ to XML - it's easier to manage different versions etc that way - but in some cases `XmlSerializer` would be more convenient.