# What is the "advised" way to load external data into an XNA4.0 Game?

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, xbox360

I am currently working on a game destined to be submitted to the XBLIG.

My question is quite simple, I was wondering which is the "advised" way to load data via an external XML file.

I need this at least for develpment (on PC) so that the Game Designer can faff about with the gameplay variables without needing to rebuild.

In xna3.1 I used the IntermediateSerializer which no longer exists for xna4.0.

I'm probably going to create a content pipeline extension for shipping, unless of course someone can propose an amazing answer that works on both PC and XBox! :D

Thanks,

Comment: Might want to ask over at: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ :)

Comment: I think the content pipeline is only available when game studio is installed; just something to be aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first of all, `IntermediateSerializer` ***does*** [exist in XNA 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.content.pipeline.serialization.intermediate.intermediateserializer(v=XNAGameStudio.40).aspx)!

***However***, XNA 4.0 changed from targeting the .NET 2.0 framework to targeting the .NET 4.0 framework, which comes in two flavours. The XNA runtime assemblies target the *compact framework*, but the Content Pipeline assemblies target the full framework. You will need to go into your project properties and change the target framework to allow you to use `IntermediateSerializer`.

In addition, the *Content Pipeline* is *not available* on Xbox 360, **and** *neither* is it available on Windows without the full XNA Game Studio installed. Which means you can't use `InterpediateSerializer` when running on Xbox 360 *or* for distribution on Windows (applies to both XNA 3.1 and 4.0).

So if you want to use it at runtime, during development, the solution is to add a specific build target for development on Windows to your project. Give it a pre-processor definition for `#ifdef DEVELOPMENT` to wrap your code in, make target the (much bulkier) full .NET 4.0 Framework, and add an assembly reference to `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline` (where `IntermediateSerializer` lives).

(I will leave figuring out conditional framework targeting and assembly referencing as something for you to research - I'm pretty sure it requires hand-editing the project file. Or you could just create and maintain a new project file in parallel.)

So all that leaves is the question of what to do in your distribution versions, where you *don't* have `IntermediateSerializer`?

That is **extremely easy**: You can drag your XML file into your content project. The default Content Pipeline XML importer takes your XML, runs it through `IntermediateSerializer` for you, creating an `XNB` file. You can then load that file as content at runtime, via the `ContentManager`. ([see also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054333/parsing-this-xml-file-to-a-dictionary/6056169#6056169))

(Rather than sticking a bunch of conditionals in your loading code, I recommend using this method normally (at load time), and then only using the `IntermediateSerializer` method for your "reload the XML" code path.)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer!
In previous builds with xna3.1 I just supplied the IntermediateSerializer dll with the distribution (on windows) to make it work. I'll be able to try that tonight, thanks a lot!

Comment: Oops, thanks for that :) It was only internally distributed anyhoo ^^